# How to use Non static async method in static method?

Tags: c#, .net

How Can I use BuildUrl in View Class inside static method? Who can advice or give example

```
public class View:IHttpHandler

//can not do like this -->>private readonly ILinkPlus _linkPlus;

{

//Can not create ctor like this --> public View(ILinkPlus linkPlus){_linkPlus=linkPlus;}

private static void ViewDetailRecord()

{

//??????????? and can not do like this-->>

var obj = _linkPlus.BuildUrl();

}

}
```

This is how BuildUrl() method implemented inside another class and it works fine

```
public class LinkPlus:ILinkPlus

{

private readonly IContent _content;

public LinkPlus(IContent content)

    {

        _content= content;

    }
public async Task<string> BuildUrl()

    {                   

        var recordName = await _content.GetRecordNameAsync();           

        return recordName ;

    }
}

public interface ILinkPlus

{

    Task<string> BuildUrl();

}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: You have two issues: One is accessing the non-static data member `_linkPlus` from a static method (can be done, requires naming the instance owning the member because a static method doesn't have an implicit `this` instance).  Two is that the method you are calling on `_linkPlus` returns a `Task<string>` and you almost certainly wanted a `string`.

Comment: Looks like you need `async Task ViewDetailRecord` then `await...`

Comment: @Charlieface Can not do like you suggest coz ViewDetailRecordused using in another places like static

Comment: When using async/await you really should have it from the bottom of your call stack all the way to the top.

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewDetailRecord method, use async Task instead of void and call the buildURL method with await.

Use like below:

```
private static async Task ViewDetailRecord()    
{      
    var obj = await _linkPlus.BuildUrl();  
     .....Your codes..............  
}
```

Comment: I tried like you suggested it is not working